# Recording SWF and Converting to FLV

Tags: c#, video, audio, flv

I have tonss of videos in database and they can't be accessed directly but I can play them one by one and can record them. Now I want to write a program (probably in C#) that will get a URL and will start Internet Explorer or any other default browser to start the link. Once the link will be started, video will be playing.

Now my job is to record the video for "x" seconds along with audio. I can record the video by taking screenshots very frequently but what about audio and it's quality? Do I need to put microphone in a sound proof room attached with speaker so that I record it or I can directly pull the audio off from audio interface card before letting it toward the speakers?

Any ideas?

Umair

Answer (score 0):

This is not wise at all. You will have a *huge* quality loss recording video from screen and re-encoding it, not to mention the time this will take.

You should find a way to access those videos directly from the database, and run them through a converter like `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`rtmpdump`](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) to retrieve the video stream as a .flv? Of course, you will need to parse the stream information from the respective web pages, but that should be manageable.